Tensor product Ore division ring of fractions
In this article, Lemma 4.2, it seems to be saying that
$$K\otimes_{\mathscr{U}(Q)}\mathscr{F}(Q) = 0$$
where $\mathscr{U}(Q)$ is the universal enveloping algebra of the finitely generated Lie algebra $Q$ over the field $K$ and $\mathscr{F}(Q)=\mathscr{U}(Q)(\mathscr{U}(Q)\setminus\{0\})^{-1}$
but I tried to prove it defining the morphism
\begin{align*}
K\otimes_{\mathscr{U}(Q)}\mathscr{F}(Q) & \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}(Q) \\
x\otimes y & \longmapsto xy
\end{align*}
and try to show that it's $0$ unfortunately it seems very surjective since the image of $1\otimes y$ is $y$ for all $y\in\mathscr{F}(Q)$, what seems to be the problem?

The first question to ask is, how is $K$ a $\mathcal{U}(Q)$-module? Are there nontrivial things in $\mathcal{U}(Q)$ which operate via multiplication with zero? Because then you can compare your wrong proof of surjectivity to an object like $\mathbb Z/p \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$, or better yet, $K \otimes_{K[x]} K(x)$, where the left $K$ is the $K[x]$-module $K[x]/(x)$.

@TorstenSchoeneberg It's literally introduced as the trivial $\mathscr{U}(Q)$-module.... thank you

Apparently my comment answered the question, so I'll just copy it here:

The first question to ask is, how is $K$ a $\mathcal{U}(Q)$-module? Are there nontrivial things in $\mathcal{U}(Q)$ which operate via multiplication with zero? Because then you can compare your wrong proof of surjectivity to an object like $Z/p\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$, or better yet, $K\otimes_{K[x]} K(x)$, where the left $K$ is the $K[x]$-module $K[x]/(x)$.

And apparently indeed $K$ was defined as "the trivial $\mathcal{U}(Q)$-module". (NB: This does presumably not mean that all of $\mathcal{U}(Q)$ acts trivially on it, but everything after the zero-th filtration step $K$ itself.)
